Error in importing nanoid package in Node
I'm trying to create the frontend for a basic web app (Vanilla JS) and import the nanoid package, but I'm facing an error when attempting to import the package. My file structure is:
- project
  - node-modules
  - package.json
  - src
     - client
        - app.js
        - index.js
        - index.html

In the browser console, I get the following error:
Failed to resolve module specifier "nanoid". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

For further reference, my JS files look as follows:

app.js
import { nanoid } from "nanoid";
//import other stuff from local js files

export class App {
   async render(root){
      // doing stuff that works as expected

      someButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
         console.log(nanoid());
      })
   }
}



index.js
import { App } from "./app.js";

const app = new App();
await app.render('root');

where root is a div element in the body of index.html. In index.html, I load the script as
<script type = "module" src="./index.js"></script>



I then run an HTTP server in the project directory with the proper path.
I have tried common fixes like setting "type" = "module" at the top level of package.json, importing the script into index.html as a module, clearing npm cache, uninstalling and reinstalling the package, downgrading to the package version 3.0.0, etc. I created a test.js in the client directory as:
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid'

console.log(nanoid());

and ran node test.js which logs correctly to the console. This is why I am confused as to why I am facing this error - I also tried this with other common packages like random in a similar fashion (logging to the console) and obtained the same error, so I know it's not a package bug.
